# Unparseable date with symbolic timezone

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm having problems with parsing date in format like this `"Dec 21 2017 12:30:45 AM ALMT"`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
sdf.parse("Dec 21 2017 12:30:45 AM ALMT");
```

Using the SimpleDateFormat getting me stuck with `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec 21 2017 12:30:45 AM ALMT"`

Where am I getting wrong? Checked pattern more than once with Java documentation, it looks as recommended.

Comment: Your code works on my computer. A locale issue?

Comment: What is ALMT???

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. It doesn’t answer your question, but I recommend you move on to [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @MauricePerry ALMT is [Alma-Ata Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/almt). But you are right, those three and four letter abbreviations are not standardized and therefore give rise to confusion, misconception and errors.

Comment: It is a `Locale` issue. You could give it a try with `Locale.ROOT` as one answer of the duplicate explains. Or maybe use the correct locale anyway. And after that, move on to `java.time` ...